# make model , controller ,seeder,factory,migration in custom folder

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, model, controller

Is there any way to create model with all other classes in custom folder

when I try

```
php artisan make:model locations/City --all
```

I expect to create

```
controllers/locations/CitiesController

models/locations/City
```

etc.

only create a model in a custom folder (locations)
but the controller and others in the main folder

Comment: Which Laravel version?

Answer (score 0):

This feature exists in [Laravel 8](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#generating-model-classes) and [Laravel 9](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#generating-model-classes). If you're using any of the earlier versions, it won't work.